# WordPress cURL and wp_remote_post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, curl

So my problem is that i used until now in one of my wordpress plugins `cURL` for a `POST` request, but now i need to use `wp_remote_post()`.

`wp_remote_post` seems simple but i can't get it to work. So my question is: could someone show my how the following `cURL` can be transfered to `wp_remote_post` ?

The cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

My version of wp_remote_post

```
$result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers' => $headers,
    'body' => json_encode($fields) )
);
```

I get a 401 error with `wp_remote_post` because the authorization didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it. For some reason it is working now, after adding `httpversion` and the `sslverify`.

Hope this helps someone:

```
$result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers' => $headers,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'sslverify' => false,
    'body' => json_encode($fields))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer did not work for me.
Maybe because its from 2015.

Im am using `wp_remote_post()` from my WordPress plugin.
No `curl()` calls.

The following did work, note the few additions: timeout, redirection and blocking.
WP 5+

```
$result = wp_remote_post($url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers' => $headers,
    'timeout'     => 60, // added
    'redirection' => 5,  // added
    'blocking'    => true, // added
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'sslverify' => false,
    'body' => json_encode($fields))
);
```